# How to add event handler for dynamically created controls at runtime?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on C# windows application. my application get controls(button,text box,rich text box and combo box etc)from custom control library and placed them into form dynamically at run time. how i create event handler for that controls using delegate? and how to add business logic in particular custom control click event?

For Example:

i have user1, user2, user3, when user1 log in i want to show only "save" button. when user2 then only show  "add and delete" buttons and user 3 only show "add and update" buttons.text boxes and button created as per user log in information taken from DB tables.in this scenario how i handle different event(adding,saving,updating,deleting) for button save,add,delete and update for different users when form is dynamically created controls(save,add,delete and update button object is from same button class)

Answer (score 10):

With anonymous method:

```
Button button1 = new Button();
button1.Click += delegate
                    {
                        // Do something 
                    };
```

With an anonymous method with explicit parameters:

```
Button button1 = new Button();
button1.Click += delegate (object sender, EventArgs e)
                    {
                        // Do something 
                    };
```

With lambda syntax for an anonymous method:

```
Button button1 = new Button();
button1.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
                    {
                        // Do something 
                    };
```

With method:

```
Button button1 = new Button();
button1.Click += button1_Click;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do something
}
```

Further information you can find in the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

```
var t = new TextBox();
t.MouseDoubleClick+=new System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventHandler(t_MouseDoubleClick);

private void t_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
     throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

It's adding double click eventhandler to new TextBox

Answer (score 3):

I believe you could do something like this:

```
if (userCanAdd)
    container.Controls.Add(GetAddButton());
if (userCanUpdate)
    container.Controls.Add(GetUpdateButton());
if (userCanDelete)
    container.Controls.Add(GetDeleteButton());

private Button GetAddButton() {
    var addButton = new Button();
    // init properties here

    addButton.Click += (s,e) => { /* add logic here */ };
    // addButton.Click += (s,e) => Add();
    // addButton.Click += OnAddButtonClick;

    return addButton;
}

private void OnAddButtonClick (object sender, EventArgs e) { 
    // add logic here
}

// The other methods are similar to the GetAddButton method.
```